# Unity2D with Android: Lost Keystore, what can I possibly do using Unity Collaborate?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, keystore

This question has been asked before, but I haven't seen anyone talking about it in context of the collaborate feature in Unity.

Long story short, my partner (who doesn't have the keystore on his computer) pushed an update, and I restored my Unity version to it like an idiot. This wiped my Unity folder and replaced it with what he had. I lost the keystore this way.

Previously, I had also pushed an update to Unity when I did have the keystore in the root folder of the Unity folder. My first instinct was to search through that version, but alas, it's not there. I don't know why, I'd assume Unity uploads your entire root folder when you push the project.

I do have the password to both my keystore and the signature used to push the app to Google Play. I can't just create a new keystore with the same name and password, as other users here have pointed out. I do have APKs of the game before the keystore was wiped, but I doubt it'll help. I do have Google Play App Signing enabled on the Playstore, but I can't find a way for it to help me out.

I used a data recovery software (EaseUS) to see if it could recover my keystore. It could not.

Can anyone give me hope? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried system restore? You might be able to use that to recover overwritten files if you enabled it...

Comment: Thank you @Chico3001! Your answer worked. Can you post this as an answer so I can tag my issue as resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Windows and if you are lucky you may have the previous versions feature enabled, right click on your folder, select propierties and there should be a previous versions tab, select it and if it is enabled there should be several dates showing changes

In W10 is called file history

https://www.pcworld.com/article/2974385/windows/how-to-use-windows-10s-file-history-backup-feature.html